# Matrix exponentials and their derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

Is the derivative of a exponential matrix $e^{At}$, with all elements as a function of $t$, be equal to the derivative of each element separately wrt $t$, assembled into the matrix?

Sorry I’m new to Linear algebra, please help me out.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Would you mind to try to be more clear about what you are asking?

Comment: Give an example, if you're unable to write things very clearly.

Comment: You mean that if $[e^{AT}]_{ij} = f_{ij}(t)$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dt} e^{At} = \left[ \frac{d}{dt} f_{ij}(t) \right]
$$
And you are asking if this is correct? Yes it is.

Comment: @unobservable_node this is what I wanted. Thanks. Also, can we extend the same logic of laplace transform of any matrix? Are they equivalent to Laplace transform of individual elements, respectively arranged in the matrix (same logic you just explained). Sorry I couldn't articulate the question well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Here is an example that you might find helpful:

Suppose we are given the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{-1&4\\1&-1},
$$
which has eigenvalues $\lambda = -1 \pm 2i$. We find that
$$
e^{tA} = e^{-t}\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\left(2\,t\right) & 2\,\sin\left(2\,t\right)\\ -\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2\,t\right) & \cos\left(2\,t\right) \end{array}\right).
$$
Using the formula $\frac {d}{dt} e^{tA} = Ae^{tA}$, we should find that
$$
\frac{d}{dt} e^{tA} = e^{-t}\pmatrix{-1&4\\1&-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\left(2\,t\right) & 2\,\sin\left(2\,t\right)\\ -\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2\,t\right) & \cos\left(2\,t\right) \end{array}\right) 
\\= 
e^{-t}\left(\begin{array}{cc} -\cos\left(2\,t\right) -2 \sin(2\,t)& 4\cos(2s)-2\sin\left(2\,t\right)\\ -\cos(2\,t)+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2\,t\right) & 
-\cos\left(2\,t\right) - 2 \sin(2\,t)\end{array}\right)
.
$$
We can check that the result for the derivative of the upper-left entry matches: by the product rule,
$$
\frac d{dt}\left[e^{-t}\cos\left(2\,t\right)\right] = 
(-e^{-t}) \cos(2t) + e^{-t}(-2\sin(2t)) = 
e^{-t}(-\cos(2t) - 2\sin(2t)).
$$